# ng-repeat not updating on rootScope change

Tags: angularjs

I have the following `ng-repeat`, but for some reason it fails to update the `ng-disabled` value when I update `$root.currentUser.LinkedLogins`

```
 <button ng-repeat="providerName in externalProviders track by $index"               
         ng-disabled="{{ $root.currentUser.LinkedLogins.indexOf(providerName) > -1 }}">
```

I'm certain that the digest cycle occurs after I update the rootScope so why doesn't the ng-disabled update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not interpolate inside `ng-disabled` expression, since it takes an expression.

Just do:

```
ng-disabled="$root.currentUser.LinkedLogins.indexOf(providerName) > -1"
```

`{{expn}}` ==> value of an expression

In your case you would be setting a string value (true/false) to ng-disabled say `true/false` and it will set the initial state of button based on the value. However to track the subsequent updates it will set a watch on property with the name `true/false` on the scope (which obviously does not exist).

[From source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/attrs.js#L354)

```
//Here attr[normalized] will be true or false in your case
scope.$watch(attr[normalized], function ngBooleanAttrWatchAction(value) {
   attr.$set(attrName, !!value);
});
```

Side Note: I am not sure why you are referring to `$root`, if you update the property `LinkedLogins` of the rootscope property `currentUser`, you should see the update in your child scope as the `currentUser` gets protoypically inherited by any child scopes (non isolated):

```
 ng-disabled="currentUser.LinkedLogins.indexOf(providerName) > -1"
```

Answer (score 1):

With angular directives, you don't need the double curly brackets - those are mostly just used for data binding outside of a directive.

Try this:

```
 <button ng-repeat="providerName in externalProviders track by $index"               
         ng-disabled="$root.currentUser.LinkedLogins.indexOf(providerName) > -1">
```